# How to upload photo via retrofit from android device?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, image-uploading

**I have endpoint like this:**

Image Upload:
https://api.imgbb.com/1/upload

Parameters:
key (required)    :     The API key.
image (required) : A binary file, base64 data, or a URL for an image. (up to 16MB)
name (optional)    : The name of the file, this is automatically detected if uploading a file with a POST 
                    and multipart / form-data

**I want upload photo via retrofit from android device so I tried this:**

```java
public class PhotoNetworkClient {

    public static final String KEY_API="my_key";
    private static final String BASE_URL = "https://api.imgbb.com/1/";
    private static Retrofit retrofit;

    public static Retrofit getRetrofitClient(Context context) {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .build();
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .client(okHttpClient)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

```java
public interface PhotoService {
    @Multipart()
    @POST("/upload")
    Call<ResponseBody> uploadImage(@Query("key") String key, @Part() MultipartBody.Part file );
}
```

**And I am using this like:**

```
public static void testExecute(Bitmap bitmap, Context context) throws IOException {
    //Convert bitmap to byte array
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 0 /*ignored for PNG*/, bos);
    byte[] bitmapData = bos.toByteArray();
    //create file
    String currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    File f = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "temp_"+currentDate );
    f.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
    fos.write(bitmapData);
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();

    Retrofit retrofit = PhotoNetworkClient.getRetrofitClient(context);
    PhotoService uploadAPIs = retrofit.create(PhotoService.class);

    RequestBody requestFile =  RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), f);
    MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", f.getName(), requestFile);
    Call call = uploadAPIs.uploadImage(PhotoNetworkClient.KEY_API,body);
    call.enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful())
                Toast.makeText(context, "I send photo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            else
                Toast.makeText(context, "response isn't successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "on failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    });
}

});
```

I am receiving response with code 200 but the image doesn’t upload to the server

Answer (score 0):

Late to this but I was actually searching for some examples of using ImgBB API also.

I manage to upload images in the end - the codes I used were pretty similar to yours but just with a minor change:

Don't include the "1" parameter in the base URL, leave it in the POST. And that solved the problem for me.

```
BASE_URL = "https://api.imgbb.com"

@POST("/1/upload")
```